# How to get speed in Android App

Tags: android

I tried many codes and no one of them works. I tried this :

```
//This is in another void
Location location = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    location.setSpeed(0);
                    Greitis(location);

//This is in CountDownTimer which has onTick every 1 second
public void Greitis(Location location) {
        if (location.hasSpeed()) {
            speed.setText(location.getSpeed() * 3.6 + " Km/h");
        }
    }
```

Can anyone say why is it not working or write me how to properly get speed.

Comment: There is a lot of brilliant solutions are there. First do some research(at least search) before posting a question here.

Answer (score 0):

`getSpeed()` returns only the value that was set using `setSpeed(int)` (in your case always 0).

If you want to get a more or less accurate speed, there are 2 ways:

1. using your accelerometer
2. calculating the speed yourself

If you don't want to use GPS (what usually is a good idea), you should choose option 1. But number 2 isn't very complicated. Just store two GPS points with a delay of `T`. Than your speed is (according to `speed = distance/time`:

```
speed = sqrt((point2.x - point1.x) ^ 2 + (point2.y - point1.y) ^ 2) / T
```

Because `distance` is the distance between `point1` and `point2`.

Comment: This formula is two dimensional. GPS coordinates are angles ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system)) and the distance between two geographical point is the distance on the World's surface (spherical distance) ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) and [link1](https://www.math.ksu.edu/~dbski/writings/haversine.pdf) or [link2](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)).